# Android: Permission denied for /data/local/tmp/*

Tags: java, android, shell

I am trying to run a shell script through an android app. The script has a command which just runs a jar on the device. When I run this command directly on the shell using adb, everything works fine. But when I run it through the script using the android app, I get a permission denied exception (open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)) for the files created in /data/local/tmp folder. Can anyone guide in how to resolve this issue?

This is what my manifest looks like

```
<manifest ….>
   <uses-sdk …>
    <uses-permission… .>
    …
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    …
    <application …>
    …
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

**Update *8 years later***

On modern versions of Android, there is no way to run downloaded or generated code (a.k.a. [W^X violation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission)). We can only embed prebuilt binaries in the APK (or bundle) *(using **jniLibs** and other settings in **gradle.build**)* and make sure it is extracted to the native file system (*explicitly set [**android:extractNativeLibs = "true"**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#extractNativeLibs)*). Then you can run the binary from [getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#nativeLibraryDir).

---

If I understand the scenario correctly, you create the script on the fly, and use `/data/local/tmp` as an easy location that is both publicly writable and executable. Once, this was possible. But on recent versions of Android, security has been tightened.

Your app can execute files under `/data/data/${your.package}`. You can use [getContext().getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) to reliably obtain the full path. Note that you still need to use `chmod 500` to ensure that the file has **executable** permission.

If you have some fixed executables (binaries or scripts) that must be installed with your app, there is a clever trick to let the system package installer take care of all that for you: make sure the file has a name "**lib**something**.so**" and put it in `/libs/armeabi` directory under the Eclipse project root. After installation, the files will be present in [getContext().getApplicationInfo().nativeLibraryDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#nativeLibraryDir) directory with executable permissions set.

---

**PS** You don't need the **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission for this to work (maybe you need it for other things your app does).

---

**PPS** You can run a shell script from anywhere, including `/sdcard`, and you don't need executable permission for the script. Instead, use `sh -c source full.path.to.script`.

Comment: Does not work anymore since Android 10 (API 29): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478042/
This fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946068/

Comment: On Android 11 (API 30) link referred to  by @nhcodes worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the adb interface to copy and/or push files to the `/data/local/tmp` folder but if you want to use/see them in the terminal app you will need to (in adb interface) first

```
cd /data/local/tmp
```

then make a folder inside the folder. Example

```
mkdir folder
```

next change the permissions

```
chmod - R 777 folder
```

Now you have a folder you can read and write to.

A few things that I would like to know is how to make the system think that the `su` binary is in the `/system/bin` folder (without copying) because I can only get tmp... root access because even with root access, I can not remount the system directory as `rw` because the zte-paragon has its system partition formatted as a read-only file-system

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that your Andorid is not been rooted.
the "/data" have the root Permission.
So root your phone first, and give your app the permission.
you can try command:"su" int the shell change to root.

Comment: Is rooting really the problem? Because, the script works fine when I run it from the shell. i.e. when I do "sudo adb shell" and then run the script through the shell, it works as expected. But when I run the script through the app using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh "+scriptPath), the permission denied exception is thrown.

Comment: "sudo adb shell" is get Linux's ROOT, not Android. After into the shell:"shell@android:/ $", use "su", Then:"shell@android:/ #" , you get the ROOT for Android. If your Android is no rooted, "su" wouldn't work

Comment: My device is not rooted. Still, the script works fine with no permission issues if I run it through adb shell. But when I run it through the code using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh scriptPath"), I get permission issues for /data/local/tmp/ directory. How do I resolve this?

Comment: try to use :Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `/data/local/tmp` location is world-executable on your device:

```
adb shell ls -ld /data/ /data/local/ /data/local/tmp/

drwxrwx--x system   system            XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX
drwxr-x--x root     root              XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX
drwxrwx--x shell    shell             XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX
#        ^ all x here == OK!
```

If it's not, there's nothing you can do, and you need to use the standard storage (internal `/data/data/{package}` or external `/sdcard/`).

Make sure you made the file world-readable.

```
adb shell chmod o+r /data/local/tmp/myfile.txt
```

You don't need any permissions.