# Cant create a file in /tmp location of device from API

Tags: java, android

I can't create a file in a location /tmp of device. i think it is some permission issues. can you please help me..?
in my android manifest, i included following permissions:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

My activity code is as follows:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Example of a call to a native method

        try{

            write();

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
            tv.setText(tv.getText()+"  "+Register());
        //System.out.println("The value of retval is"+nativeinterface());
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public Boolean write(){
        try {

            String fcontent = "Hello world!!";
            String fpath = "/tmp/abc.txt";


            File file = new File(fpath);



            // If file does not exists, then create it
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(fcontent);
            bw.close();

            Log.d("Suceess","Sucess");
            return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("The File Not Created");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

My log is as follows:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:280)
W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:948)
```

please help me to solve this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Permission denied for /data/local/tmp/\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424602/android-permission-denied-for-data-local-tmp)

Comment: I'm truthfully drawing a blank on whether you want to close `fw`, `bw`, or both (C#'s my primary language right now, I do most of my Android development in Xamarin.Android).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html), you should use the `Context` object's [getCacheDir() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()) to get the proper location to save temporary files, which "Returns the absolute path to the application specific cache directory on the filesystem." Note that this is for *temporary* files, so if you want to persist the files "permanently" (in quotes because you can't *really* assume that a file will be permanent in a mobile device), you'll want to use a different method. Again from the documentation,

> The system will automatically delete files in this directory as disk space is needed elsewhere on the device. The system will always delete older files first...

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424602/android-permission-denied-for-data-local-tmp) as well for a similar problem.