# Cannot run program "/data/data/my.app.package/files/my-executable": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: android, processbuilder, permission-denied

I copy a binary executable to the location `context.getFilesDir()` which is the path `/data/data/my.app.package/files/my-executable`.

File permission of `/data/data/my.app.package/files/my-executable` is `-rwxr-xr-x`

Then I try to execute a command with the java `ProcessBuilder` like:

```
commands = Arrays.asList("/data/data/my.app.package/files/my-executable", "ls");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
final Process p = pb.start();
```

The statement `pb.start()` throws the following IOException:

```
Caused by java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
       at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(UNIXProcess.java)
       at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)
       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)

Cannot run program "/data/data/my.app.package/files/my-executable": error=13, Permission denied
```

I have no root access on the test phone. Until Android version 9 (API 28) it was working fine. Starting from Android 10 (API 29) I get the above IOException.

How can I run my executable in Android 10+ ? Does it work in another directory? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any solution? same problem here

Comment: It looks like there is no solution. Since API 29 it's not possible anymore to run provided binaries... :-(

Comment: Hi...Did you find any solution on that

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing the value of 'android.defaultConfig.targetSdkVersion' from '29' to '28' in 'build.gradle(Module: app)'.